# list of pointer to base class-understand code

Tags: c++, list, object, inheritance, parent

I am training to my exam in c++ and I don't understand why the code display only print function of the base class (also after I debug the code) and never go to the print of derived class.
Can you explain me why in a simple way, and does there is some issue I can do in order to also display the print function of derived class only by edit a few line of code.
Let say the number that the program generate are: 1 67 0 69 0 0 58 78.

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    A(int x):a(x){}

    void print() { cout << "a=" << a << ' '; }
};

class B:public A
{
    int b;
public:
    B(int x,int y) :A(x),b(y) {}
    void print() { A::print(); cout << "b=" << b << ' '; }
};

int main(){
    list<A*> lst;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if(rand()%2)
            lst.push_back(new A(rand() % 100));
        else
            lst.push_back(new B(rand() % 100,rand()%100));
    for (list<A*>::iterator it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); it++)
        (*it)->print();
}
```

Comment: Make `A::print()` function virtual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `print()` virtual in order for polymorphism to work.

Here is your example with suggested formatting improvements,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class A{
    int a;
public:
    A(int x):a(x){}
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "a=" << a << ' '; }
};

class B:public A{
    int b;
public:
    B(int x,int y) :A(x),b(y) {}
    void print() override { A::print(); std::cout << "b=" << b << ' '; }
};

int main(){
    std::list<A*> lst;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if(rand()%2) {
            lst.push_back(new A(rand() % 100));
        } else {
            lst.push_back(new B(rand() % 100,rand()%100));
        }
    }
    for (std::list<A*>::iterator it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); it++) {
        (*it)->print();
    }
}
```

I increased the number of printed elements, because in these settings I wasn't getting a single `b`. This said:

- You need to seed your code with [`srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) if you don't want to get the same numbers over and over again (and you need to seed it only once per program).
- If possible, you should use the [`new random number`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) generation functionality available from C++11 on.
- `override` is optional, but very encouraged, it clearly signals that the function was virtual and re-implemented.
- Most importantly you need to free the memory you allocated with `new` (using `delete`), or better yet, use the approach in @TedLyngmo answer (smart pointers)

Answer (score 2):

In order to make use of dynamic dispatch, you need to make `A::print()` `virtual`. You also need to make `A`'s destructor `virtual` to be able to `delete` objects through the base class pointer.

Since you currently do not `delete` any objects (but instead leak all `A`'s and `B`s) I suggest that you make use of a smart pointer, `std::unique_ptr<A>`, that will clean up when the `std::list` is destroyed.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>   // std::unique_ptr

class A {
    int a;

public:
    A(int x) : a(x) {}
    virtual ~A() = default;  // virtual destructor

    virtual void print() { std::cout << "a=" << a << ' '; }
};

class B : public A {
    int b;

public:
    B(int x, int y) : A(x), b(y) {}
    void print() override {
        A::print();
        std::cout << "b=" << b << ' ';
    }
};

int main() {
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<A>> lst;   // use of smart pointer

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if(rand() % 2) {
            lst.emplace_back(std::make_unique<A>(rand() % 100));
        } else {
            lst.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>(rand() % 100, rand() % 100));
        }
    }
    for(auto it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); it++) {
        (*it)->print();
    }

    // Simpler loop: A range-based for loop:
    // for(auto& ptr : lst) ptr->print();
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention freeing the memory... still early here today :)

Comment: @atru I had a "not enough coffee" experience this morning myself :-)

Comment: I think it's time to change that :D